# Adobe Illustrator rename layers alphabetically based on selection

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm trying to make a script that renames the selected layers in Adobe Illustrator based on my input. I managed to get it work only if you start from letter "A". If I'm starting from letter "B" for example, it's skipping the first layer (as it would be "A") and starts renaming only from the second layer (if I'm trying with "C", the skips the first two layers, and so on...). Is there a way to .. kind of reset the counter and so the renaming could start from the first layer in selection?

Here is my code:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument,
sel = doc.selection,
rename = prompt("Enter the name:","");
done = 0;

var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var r = /\[\w+\]/i;
var matching = rename.match( r );

var letter = str.search( matching );

if (letter>=0)
{
   for(i=letter; i<sel.length;i++)
   {

        var nextChar = str.charAt(i);

      if(nextChar){
            theRenaming=rename.replace(/\[\w+\]/, nextChar);
            sel[i].name = theRenaming;
            letter++;
            // document.write(theRenaming);
        }
        else
        sel[i].name = rename;
   }    

  //console.log(letter);
} else 
{
alert("Nothing Found!");
}
```

This is how it works:
After you select your layers, this script will ask you to Enter the name (ex: layer[A]).. it will find layer and rename it to layerA (removing the brackets) and iterate through alphabet based on selection length.

My problem: if it's letter B or C or H it will start renaming the layers only the second layer or the third respectively 8th and I want it to start with B from layer one and so on.

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Nevermind. I got it figured.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Photoshop/JavaScript script to clean up nested layers. Need foreach alternative for recursive function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606735/photoshop-javascript-script-to-clean-up-nested-layers-need-foreach-alternative)